# Post_save method in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I've have stuck in a problem where if both the person follows the each other only then it should make them friends. I'm planning to use Django signal's post save method for this. But I'm not able to make any progression in it .Please help me on this .Thanks in advance and do refer the code below and sorry for bad coding.

Models.py:

```
class Follow(models.Model):
Follower=models.ForeignKey(User, models.SET_NULL,null=True,related_name='from_user_followers',blank=True)
Followe=models.ForeignKey(User,models.SET_NULL,null=True,related_name='to_user_followers',blank=True)
created=models.DateTimeField(default=now)

@receiver(post_save, sender=Follow)    
def create_friend(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):

if created:
    see_followe_is_following_back = Follow.objects.filter(Followe=instance.Follower, Follower=instance.Followe)
    see_follower_is_following_back = Follow.objects.filter(Follower=instance.Followe, Followe=instance.Follower)
    
    try:
        if str(instance.Follower) == str(see_follower_is_following_back) and str(instance.Followe) == str(see_followe_is_following_back):
            create_friends= Friends.objects.update_or_create(from_user=instance.Followe , to_user=instance.Follower)
            return create_friends
        else:
            pass
    except Exception as e:
        return str(e)

else:
    pass 


class Friends(models.Model):
from_user=models.ForeignKey(User, models.SET_NULL,null=True,related_name='from_user_friends',blank=True)
to_user=models.ForeignKey(User,models.SET_NULL,null=True,related_name='to_user_friends',blank=True)
created=models.DateTimeField(default=now)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic to be modified like this, please try the below code.

```py
class Follow(models.Model):
    Follower=models.ForeignKey(User, models.SET_NULL,null=True,related_name='from_user_followers',blank=True)
    Followe=models.ForeignKey(User, models.SET_NULL,null=True,related_name='to_user_followers',blank=True)
    created=models.DateTimeField(default=now)

@receiver(post_save, sender=Follow)    
def create_friend(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        see_follower_is_following_back = Follow.objects.filter(Followe=instance.Follower, Follower=instance.Followe).first()
        see_followe_is_following_back = Follow.objects.filter(Follower=instance.Follower, Followe=instance.Followe).first() 
        
        try:
            if str(instance.Follower) == str(see_follower_is_following_back.Followe) and str(instance.Followe) == str(see_followe_is_following_back.Followe):
                create_friends= Friends.objects.update_or_create(from_user=instance.Followe , to_user=instance.Follower)
                return create_friends
            else:
                pass
        except Exception as e:
            return str(e)
    else:
        pass 


class Friends(models.Model):
    from_user=models.ForeignKey(User, models.SET_NULL,null=True,related_name='from_user_friends',blank=True)
    to_user=models.ForeignKey(User,models.SET_NULL,null=True,related_name='to_user_friends',blank=True)
    created=models.DateTimeField(default=now)
```

please let me know if you face any issues. and one more thing,
the following code is enough if i guess right,

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Follow)    
def create_friend(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        see_follower_is_following_back = Follow.objects.filter(Followe=instance.Follower, Follower=instance.Followe).first()
        
        if see_follower_is_following_back:
            create_friends= Friends.objects.update_or_create(from_user=instance.Followe , to_user=instance.Follower)
            return create_friends
```